# Why does Continuous Wavelet Transform have phase information at high frequencies?

Tags: wavelet-analysis, frequency

I'm playing around with `ContinuousWaveletTransform` using a sine wave of a constant frequency:

```
x = Array[# &, 4096, {0, 10}];
y = Sin[2 \[Pi] * 50 x];
c = ContinuousWaveletTransform[y, MorletWavelet[]];
WaveletScalogram[c, Automatic, Abs, ImageSize -> Large]
WaveletScalogram[c, Automatic, Arg, ImageSize -> Large]
```

The output of the first line seems fine: [image]

But the phase has some unusual features: [image]

Why does the phase have information present at scales above and below scale 4 (the signal frequency)? What are those features below scale 5?